# Cannot run simple servlet with use of annotations

Tags: java, servlets, annotations

I am new java programmer. So I do understand the process of running servlet through mapping etc in the web.xml and I also can launch the servlet through annotation, my question is when I use the annotation, and run the project on the server, why do I have to write the serlvet name in the URL after project name for it to launch.

Is there any way without using web.xml file at all, giving an annotation and then when I run project on server that it would automatically launch and run the servlet? Instead of my writing the servlet name and hitting enter for it to launch.

```
@WebServlet(urlPatterns = {"/GetDate"})

public class GetDate extends HttpServlet{

    @Override
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws ServletException, IOException {
        Date date =new Date();

        resp.setContentType("text/html");//this says we will send back html type 
        //get a pen to write back
        PrintWriter pen=resp.getWriter();
        //write back
        pen.write(date.toString());

    }
}
```

I would like the above simple servlet to just launch automatically as soon as I select run on server from eclipse.

Comment: What do you mean "write the servlet name"?  What is an example URL?

Comment: So the name of my servlet is GetServlet and when I run the project on server, it takes me to error404 page with URL localhost:8080/myprojectname/  and then all I have to do is add GetServlet to that url and it run fine..... I want it to run automatically....

Answer (score 0):

You can specify load on startup in annotation, then the servlet's `init()` method is invoked when the web server starts

```
@WebServlet(urlPatterns = {"/GetDate"}, loadOnStartup=1)
public class GetDate extends HttpServlet{

@Override
public void init() throws ServletException {
    // do some init stuff
}
```

Comment: I am getting lots of red underline errors with this. I cannot access the request and response objects of HTTP..... and if I call the init method from doGet to pass the req and resp , it says cannot override....

Comment: I have to use the resp.getWriter() and also to setContentType... the request and response objects are not available inside the in it and I can't seem to somehow use them inside the init. I tried putting the whole doGet method inside init but that gave bigger errors. Can you tell me how you would use that init with doGet(req, resp); ??

Comment: so you need to recevie an HTTP request. this cannot be done automatically at server start time - some external program needs to invoke that HTTP request. you need to understand what processing exactly needs to be invoked at start up

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `@WebServlet(urlPatterns = {"/GetDate"})` write like this `@WebServlet("/GetDate")`

```
@WebServlet("/GetDate")
public class GetDate extends HttpServlet{

    @Override
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws ServletException, IOException {
        Date date =new Date();

        resp.setContentType("text/html");//this says we will send back html type 
        //get a pen to write back
        PrintWriter pen=resp.getWriter();
        //write back
        pen.write(date.toString());

    }
}
```

Comment: yea, I had it like that before it doesn't work, well I mean it does but I have to write GetDate adding it to the URL on the browser. Then it runs fine. I want it to run automatically when I say run as server on the project

Comment: There really isn't a difference between using the `urlPatterns` and not.  The `urlPatterns` allows you to create any number of patterns - i.e. `@WebServlet(urlPatterns = {"/GetDate", "/blah"})`.  By specifying only one it ends up being the same thing either way.

Answer (score 0):

It's all in the @WebServlet notation.  If you change your code to be:

```
@WebServlet(urlPatterns = {"/"})
public class GetDate extends HttpServlet {

    @Override
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws ServletException, IOException {
        Date date =new Date();

        resp.setContentType("text/html");//this says we will send back html type
        //get a pen to write back
        PrintWriter pen=resp.getWriter();
        //write back
        pen.write(date.toString());

    }
}
```

Then the servlet is served at the `/` URL (after your webapplication name)

Be careful doing this.  Traditionally you serve HTML resources from the `/` location.  If you take this over with your servlet then you can't serve HTML.  Additionally if you have more than one servlet then which one gets the `/` path - where do the rest go?  It can be a bit self documenting to have the URL match the servlet.  Note that there is no need to keep it the same name as the servlet - call it `/myBigLongURLMapping` if you like - the name is up to you.